# Refactoring Java8 code with Functional Interface

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

Input:

```
public BigDecimal getMaxValuation(ServiceData data) {
    System.out.println("getMaxValuation()");
    BigDecimal calculatedAmount;
    //4 String returnValue = getReturnValue(data);
    Function<ServiceData,String> returnValueFn = this::getReturnValue;
    BigDecimal orderSize = getOrderSize(returnValueFn.apply(data),60);
    Predicate<String> gasPredicate = "GAS"::equalsIgnoreCase;
    Predicate<String> oilPredicate = "OIL"::equalsIgnoreCase;
    if(gasPredicate.test(returnValueFn.apply(data)))
        calculatedAmount = callA(data.getValuation())
    else if(oilPredicate.test(returnValueFn.apply(data)))
        calculatedAmount = callB(data.getValuation())
    else
        calculatedAmount = callC(data.getValuation())
    return calculatedAmount;
}

public String getReturnValue(ServiceData data){
    System.out.println("getReturnValue()");
    return returnValue;
}
```

In the above function `getMaxValuation()`, when we comment line#4 and replace it with a `Function<ServiceData,String>`,
`getReturnValue()` is getting called 3 times during the execution. But when we uncomment the line #4 and remove all the
`Function<ServiceData,String>` related change the `getReturnValue()` is getting called only once.

When we use `Function` is there any way to achieve the same behavior ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  In one case you invoke the function once, in the other case you invoke it 3 times.  If you want to only invoke it once using the `Function` object, just do `String returnValue = returnValueFn.apply(data);`?

Comment: Calling function.apply 3 times is equivalent to calling getReturnValue(data) 3 times. The previous commenter shows you how  to call the function once. If I may be so bold, I'm not sure any of these changes are really making your new code any more "functional" either figuratively or literally..

Comment: @Atmas, Thanks. is there any suggestion to change that code into a functional unit ?

Comment: @MarkPeters, Thanks a lot for your suggestion!!

Comment: @busywithJava, It's too much to explain inline and probably out of scope for SO as a platform to explain it all. I would encourage you to searching up some good articles introducing the concepts online in Java. There are many concepts. If you're familiar with Object Oriented Programming, think of this as a concept that's about that big.. so it'll take some time investment to examine, wrap your head around it and practice it. You're on the right path though.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you invoke a method directly or using a functional interface, the logic of invoking it once and storing the result in a local variable to avoid repeated evaluation doesn’t change.

So far, your rewriting of the direct invocations into uses of a functional interface looks like an end in itself, without actually improving anything but only making the code more complicated.

One way of using functional programming to improve your code would be using a map of functions to replace the `if`-`else` ladder by a single lookup:

```java
static final Map<String, Function<Valuation,BigDecimal>> METHOD;
static {
    Map<String, Function<Valuation,BigDecimal>> m
        = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    m.put("GAS", ContainingClass::callA);
    m.put("OIL", ContainingClass::callB);
    METHOD = Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
}

public BigDecimal getMaxValuation(ServiceData data) {
    // don't know how to incorporate this, as it was entirely unused
    // BigDecimal orderSize = getOrderSize(getReturnValue(data), 60);

    return METHOD.getOrDefault(getReturnValue(data), ContainingClass::callC)
        .apply(data.getValuation());
}
```

Where `Valuation` refers to the return type of `ServiceData.getValuation()` and `ContainingClass` is the declaring class of `callA`, `callB`, and `callC`, assuming `static` methods.

If these methods are non-`static`, the code would have to look like

```java
static final Map<String, BiFunction<ContainingClass,Valuation,BigDecimal>> METHOD;
static {
    Map<String, BiFunction<ContainingClass,Valuation,BigDecimal>> m
        = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    m.put("GAS", ContainingClass::callA);
    m.put("OIL", ContainingClass::callB);
    METHOD = Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
}

public BigDecimal getMaxValuation(ServiceData data) {
    return METHOD.getOrDefault(getReturnValue(data), ContainingClass::callC)
        .apply(this, data.getValuation());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed explanation.